# Googlesheets Horizontal lookup inside INDEX(MATCH())

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have a googlesheet that takes training data from a sheet (master plan) and populates another sheet (athlete) with the individual reps for that particular session depending on which squad the athlete is on, which weeks session they are completing and which week they are completing. This would then provide specific targets for each rep of the session.

I have managed to look up each sessions description using INDEX(MATCH()) however, I'm now struggling to work out what I do to pull out the individual reps for a particular session.

I think I need to do some kind of lookup so that for example the value in E11 first matches the correct week, squad and session but then pulls out the correct rep for the column that E11 is in. This would then repeat for cells F11, G11 and H11 for the first rep, and then the second rep would be populated in M, N, O and P11 etc.

I'm struggling to grasp exactly what I need to do to lookup these values. Any help would be appreciated

The sheet can be found here for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j0ilgZDSgyv02QasxQxkiNefMsX6TNdN2BI7XpJQqUM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have the horizontal lookup working using ```=HLOOKUP(T8,'MASTER PLAN'!H1:W,4,0)``` but I don't want to hardcode the row4, that needs to be dynamic based on the row containing the week

Comment: Could you share more details about what would be the expected result?

Comment: Sure. So Each week in the ATHLETE sheet has several exercises associated with it. These are based on the squad the athlete is in and the session being completed.

The athlete selects their squad using the dropdown in F3. The Description of each session for the year is then populated and this works so far.

Comment: The next step is to populate the session data. Each session is made up of a number of reps and this is detailed on the MASTER PLAN sheet.. For each rep the time/distance may differ etc but each rep of the session is then entered into the ATHLETE sheet for the required week. You can see an example of this for "Week 1, Session 1" on row 14